# Why is my attempt to clone this django repository failing?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to clone a django repository, but I keep running into problems. I am trying to do this through a virtualenv.

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` I am met with the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\AutismCenterSite\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('model/', include('Model.urls', namespace = 'Model')),
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\Model\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\Model\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from joblib import load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'
```

However , I have installed joblib.

If I just run `python manage.py runserver` I am met with this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\mukes\Desktop\Oman_Autism\Web-App-for-Autism-Center\manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my approach and what I can do to fix it.

for reference here are the steps I ran to set up my virtual env:

```
PS C:\Users\mukes> py -m pip install --user virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.3/3.3 MB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.6
  Downloading distlib-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 468.5/468.5 kB 944.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.11
  Downloading filelock-3.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting platformdirs<4,>=3.2
  Using cached platformdirs-3.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Installing collected packages: distlib, platformdirs, filelock, virtualenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed distlib-0.3.6 filelock-3.12.0 platformdirs-3.5.1 virtualenv-20.23.0

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS C:\Users\mukes> py -m venv env
PS C:\Users\mukes> .\env\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best answer, but I think you just forgot to install Django

Comment: It looks like that's true, but the main problem is likely that he hasn't installed it after activating a virtual env. I think the issue is that he needs to install it a second time after the env is activated. It could be helpful to include details about how activating and deactivating a virtual env change your installed libraries as well as how to manage installs with and without an env

Answer (score 0):

`pip install django`

And then in the project directory:

`python manage.py runserver`

Should solve the initial problem but I imagine you will need to install the requirements, generally this is done like so:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

But that depends on where this file is in your project structure.

Comment: But I've already installed Django

Comment: Virtualenv changes your python environment. When you create a new virtualenv, it essentially starts blank with no libraries installed. After activating the virtualenv, you need to run `pip install django` again to install it inside the virtualenv.

Comment: @MukeshArvindhParanthaman I'd be more than happy to accept I was wrong if you were willing to try and install the requirements file inside of your virtualenv and then trying to run the server. (Please note that any subsequent issues unrelated to missing packages should be raised as a separate question rather than added to this one).